# Big-O Notation | Time Complexity - nested loop with 'and' keyword

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I am studying Big-O Notation in Python.

I have unclear what the time complexity of the following code would be:

```
for elem in list_1:
    if elem in list_2 and elem in list_3:
        print(elem)
```

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` are denoted by `m`, `n`, and `p` respectively, the time complexity will be `O(m * (n + p))`. Because the outer loop runs `m` times, and in each iteration the condition `if` can take `O(n + p)` comparison to check `elem` is contained in the corresponding lists or not.

Comment: If `list_3` is longer and the first condition is `True`, then you are adding at least `O(list_3_len * m)` which will have more impact than `n`

Comment: Thank you OmG.
Just to clarify, with the following denotation:
list_1 is z
list_2 is n
list_3 is m

the time complexity is O(z*(n+m)), is this correct?

Comment: @DeepSpace Right. My bad. I thought the inner loop was `list1` and `list2`.